# What is matrix norm in (Collins, 2001)

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, exponential-family

I am studying "[A generalization of PCA to the exponential family](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2078-a-generalization-of-principal-components-analysis-to-the-exponential-family.pdf)" (Collins et al., 2001) and I don't understand some notations.

What is the meaning of the matrix squared norm on page 6 ? Is it a frobenius norm?

If it's a matrix... what does matrix quotient (division) mean ?

If it's a scalar, is it equivalent to the following notation ?

$A^{(t)}=\frac{1}{\left \|\mathbf{V}^{(t-1)}  \right \|^2}\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{V}^{(t-1)})^T$

Comment: The wiki on matrix norms was helping me a few days ago. I think it's pretty good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While $V$ is dimension $l \times d$, in that section Collins et. al. write, "First, we concentrate on the simplest case where there is just a single component so that $l = 1$." That makes $V$ just a vector and $\|V\|$ the regular 2-norm for vectors.

It doesn't matter in this case, but in my experience when texts or papers refer to the norm of a matrix, it often is the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms).